# Do soldering glasses protect eyes from capacitor explosion

Tags: soldering, safety, electrolytic-capacitor

I am concerned about safety while working with electrolytic capacitors.

Can I use soldering safety glasses to protect my eyes while working with electrolytic capacitors?

Comment: why are you afraid of them to explode? are you doing it on purpose?

Comment: This question is quite meaningless without knowing the *amount of energy stored* in the capacitors. Please tell us the energies involved.

Comment: @VladimirCravero no. not on purpose. but we had a blind man who has became blind coz of capacitor explosion.

Comment: @KubaOber it is range of 48 volt circuit.

Comment: A blind man? That's crazy... You should revise your gear, procedures and possibly the circuits you work on. That's not something you should ask here.

Comment: @zahmati You've said what voltages are involved, now tell us what *energies* are stored in the capacitor. Recall that `E=1/2*C*V^2`, where `C` is capacitance and `V` is voltage. It'd be also helpful to know what's the ESR of the capacitors, as that will limit the power.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're working with that sort of stuff and anticipate trouble you may wish to get chemical rated safety glasses eg. ANSI Z87.1–2010 with D3 splash protection. These have side shields as well.

In some cases (very high power circuits) full face shield protection (or arc flash suits) may be called for.

[image: http://arcflashppc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/100-cal-Switching-suit.png]

This would be somewhat of an extreme precaution for wiring up a typical solderless breadboard with 555s. It's impossible for us to really tell what your situation is.

Unanticipated venting and explosions are very rare occurrences in most conditions. If you're working with (say) 5V DC circuits, it is exceedingly unlikely anything potentially harmful would happen unless you're doing something really silly like peering at a reversed capacitor from inches away.

Comment: +1 for *"somewhat of an extreme precation for wiring up solderless breadboards"*.